# iOS NSURLConnection JSON Failing

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, ssl, httpwebrequest

I am a little unstuck, I usually use MKNetworkKit or some Library, but this time I am having to do a manual HTTP request because I want to set the body data.

This is my request:

```
NSData* data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:questionDict
                                               options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:Nil];

NSString* aStr;
aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:fullAPIURL_URL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:aStr]];

NSLog(@"Data: %@",aStr);

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

It's a SSL HTTPS if this helps?

I then deal with the response like so;

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@",response);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [receivedData_ appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data", [receivedData_ length]);
    NSString *responeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData_
                                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@",responeString);

    // Assume lowercase
    if ([responeString isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
        // Deal with true
        return;
    }
    // Deal with an error
}
```

I just get this in the Logs;

```
{ status code: 403, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, must-revalidate";
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 48;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Mon, 06 Jan 2014 10:22:40 GMT";
    Expires = "Mon, 06 Jan 2014 10:22:40 GMT";
    P3P = "policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"ALL DSP COR CURa OUR IND COM NAV CNT\"";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = Apache;
    "X-Powered-By" = PleskLin;
} }
Succeeded! Received 0 bytes of data
Response:
```

Any help appreciated, I have tested this using a CURL client and it works as it should do. I think it's something to do with authentication using SSL?!

Comment: The status code is a big clue here. A status code of 403 is "[Forbidden](http://httpstatus.es/403)". If authentication was the issue, you would expect a 401. It may be useful to show us your cURL command.

Comment: You are missing a header field. Ask for all the key value  header & body from the team who developed the API

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my own question. For others reference it was the below line;

```
[request setHTTPBody:[aStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I missed the "dataUsingEncoding"